# Trying to get started tracing Python features and behavior through the source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cpython

I want to be able to investigate and trace through the Python source code to see how things work under the hood, and to resolve doubts about features that are not explicitly documented in the reference document.

I would like to have some starting information on how to go about this, because it's pretty overwhelming. I can read C, so I have that going on for me. Besides that, the task seems a little intimidating without at least a slight amount of guidance.

For example, let's say I wanted to document how attribute reference is implemented in Python. How would I go about tracing what happens when an attribute reference expression is present in a Python program?

Perhaps an overview of how the source code is organized and what each part does would be helpful, along with some "walk=thru" examples, such as the "attribute reference" case.

I searched for information on this but there doesn't seem to be much.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a good Python debugger would help? I would try using the [PyDev plugin for Eclipse](http://pydev.org/). That would at least help you trace what special python methods (such as `__getattr__()` or `__setattr__()`) are called when you reference an attribute of a class. If you need to go deeper, you can look at the [Python C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/) or even the [Python C Source Code](http://svn.python.org/view/).

Comment: OP is asking about an intro to the Python C sources!

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of using a debugger for this. I'll take a look at this possibility (although at the moment I'm not using Eclipse.) As for the C API and the source code, that would definitely be ideal. Just looking for the least painful way to get started with that (is there anything like that?)

Comment: Looks like you can debug down at the C source level using [GDB with Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb)

Answer (score 1):

There is a trace module in the python standard library.  It has several modes, and can be used to print every line of python code as it is executed like this:

```
python -m trace -t myscript.py
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/trace.html

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. I'm going to take a look at this right away and see what information I can gather with it. The obsessive compulsive in me still would like to know how to be able to dig into the code eventually though. Not sure it would be a practical endeavor, but I can see it being so if only for fun.

Comment: Gave this a try. It's certainly useful, but I'm not sure it has the required level of detail. For example, I'm not getting python special method calls (like when instantiating an object and so forth.) Maybe there is an option you can set in trace for this although I didn't see one right away. I'll take a look.